# resume activity from where it stopped without lose data

Tags: java, android

Hi i've problem with activities because i'm Newbie in Android
i have two activities :
when the first activity finishes, the second begins and the  second activity are change in it's content elemnts

---

( This in the first "default" Activity )

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

        final Context context = this;
        AppPrefs appPrefs = new AppPrefs(context);
        String Last_Activity = appPrefs.getValue("Last_Activity");
         if(Last_Activity == "listV"){
             finish();
             Intent i = new Intent(this, NewClas.class);
             startActivity(i);



         }
}
```

when app is in background then i open it:
every elements that had changed became as what it was ,

i mean that All changes returned as before

What I want is resume activity and appear it's changes that it was making when app was in background.

Sorry for my English
i hope someone helps me
Thanks a Lot ..

Comment: Take a look of this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh.. Your If condition never become **true**,

It should be like,

```
 if(Last_Activity.equals("listV")){ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) to save any values you want in a bundle and then restoring them in [onRestoreInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29).